# How to make multiple referential integrity conditions in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL statement that should add me some constraints. In that statement I want to set on two constraints two referential integrity conditions.

Here is my statement:

```
ALTER TABLE Vertraege
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Kunde_Vertraege FOREIGN KEY(K_ID)
        REFERENCES Kunde(K_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Standort_Vertraege FOREIGN KEY(S_ID)
        REFERENCES Standort(S_ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT FK_Mitarbeiter_Vertraege FOREIGN KEY(M_ID)
        REFERENCES Mitarbeiter(M_ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT FK_Dienstleistung_Vertraege FOREIGN KEY(D_ID)
        REFERENCES Dienstleistung(D_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Compliance_Vertraege FOREIGN KEY(C_ID)
        REFERENCES Compliance(C_ID);
```

So the problem ist, that I get an error because of this.

```
Notification 1785, level 16, status 0, line 28
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Mitarbeiter_Vertraege' on table 'vertreage' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Notification 1750, level 16, status 1, line 28
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

Is it possible to set multiple referential integrity conditions and if not, how can I make multiple of them in SQL? Something like `ALTER CONSTRAINT`...

**EDIT**

Brian asked for this. On my table mitarbeiter I have following constraints. The strange thing is, they work

```
ALTER TABLE Mitarbeiter
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Adresse_Mitarbeiter FOREIGN KEY(AD_ID)
        REFERENCES Adresse(AD_ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT FK_Standort_Mitarbeiter FOREIGN KEY(S_ID)
        REFERENCES Standort(S_ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT FK_Abteilung_Mitarbeiter FOREIGN KEY(AB_ID)
        REFERENCES Abteilung(AB_ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: It looks like the error is for a different constraint than the statement you posted.  The error mentions a table called "Trust", but your code is altering table "Vertraege".

Comment: Is it possible? Definitively yes. Now, where's that `FK_employee_contracts` constraint? It's not in the question.

Comment: My bad, I translated it and forgot to change the things that should stay the same...

Comment: What FK constraints do you have on `Mitarbeiter`, and what FK constraints do you have that reference `Vertraege`?

Comment: @Brian I added it in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message mentions "multiple cascade paths", and with the additional constraints that you added to your question, my first suspicion that there is an interaction between the following items (edited from your initial post):

```
ALTER TABLE Vertraege
    CONSTRAINT FK_Standort_Vertraege FOREIGN KEY(S_ID)
        REFERENCES Standort(S_ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT FK_Mitarbeiter_Vertraege FOREIGN KEY(M_ID)
        REFERENCES Mitarbeiter(M_ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE Mitarbeiter
    CONSTRAINT FK_Standort_Mitarbeiter FOREIGN KEY(S_ID)
        REFERENCES Standort(S_ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
```

So you've got a constraint that goes directly from `Vertraege` to `Standort`, and another that goes from `Vertraege` through `Mitarbeiter` to `Standort`.  My first suggestion would be to remove `FK_Standort_Vertraege` and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: But the problem is, that I need need FK_Standort_Vertraege

Comment: What does `FK_Standort_Vertraege` do that isn't done by `FK_Mitarbeiter_Vertraege` in conjunction with `FK_Standort_Mitarbeiter`?

Comment: What do you mean with that?

Comment: Why do you need `FK_Standort_Vertraege`?  What would happen if you removed it?

Comment: This is a contracts database. The foreign key `FK_Standort_Vertraege` references to the table "Locations". I need this `FK_Standort_Vertraege` because every contract has a location where it gets created

Comment: Is the "location where it (the contract) gets created" different from the location of the employees that do the work on the contract?

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess, since the question does not include all the related tables.

You are trying to create a foreign key constraint from the table `Vertraege` to the table `Mitarbeiter`. It seems, however, there's already another [reverse] foreign key constraint (not shown) from the table `Mitarbeiter` to the table `Vertraege`. I can't be sure since you don't include the definition of the table `Mitarbeiter`.

SQL Server considers this a "cyclic relationship". This is all "legal", however. Nothing wrong with it. Well... as long as some of them **are nullable**, or they **can be deferrable** (but SQL Server does not implement the latter). The cyclic relationship may not only involve two tables, but also three or more. It's not clear from the question how many tables are involved, however.

The problem stems from the "cascade delete/update" rules you want to specify. This rules can possibly lead to massive data deletion or updating by a simple innocuous `DELETE` or `UPDATE`, such as:

```
delete from Vertraege where ID = 123
```

This statement seems to be deleting a single row. However, your cascade deletion rule can end up deleting thousands of rows from multiple tables at once without further confirmation. Is that what you want?

In any case, SQL Server doesn't like those cyclic cascade deletes/updates, since it considers them [justifiable] dangerous, and decides not to allow them.

Comment: This problem can only happen if I use cascade like everywhere. But I want to use where it makes sense to use it. In example: If a concat is made with a worker and a customer a new record gets created. But what if the the worker leaves the company? Then it makes sense to use cascade, because you still want your concat in the database

Comment: If the worker leaves the company you rarely delete a row. In real life applications, you "deactivate" it by changing its state. Deleting the worker may have massive implications, like rewriting history. That can lead to wrong reporting of previous months: for example showing less sales than the actual ones, since some rows are no more. I have rarely seen `CASCASE DELETE` or `CASCADE UPDATE` in real apps. I consider those more like ivory castle constructs suitable for a professor in a university, but not for a business.

Comment: But in Theory for school project it is useful, because we have this in our school documents explained to use it like this. But yes you are right. It would make more sense to set a status to the worker, like active or deactive like you said